# Which one to use Http Handler or Http Module

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, httpmodule

We want to do something like we have to execute some piece of code in each request to the application. We want to use this same code in multiple applications.

What this code will do is, this will check the incoming request and according to some conditions it will decide whether it has to redirect or not.

So while searching i found that we can use either http handler or http module. But i am not sure about which one has to chose in this case? Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpModule` in this case. It sits in the pipeline where you can inspect each and every request.

How To Create an ASP.NET HTTP Module Using Visual C# .NET

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307996

`HttpHandler` is altogether different thing. If you implement HttpHandler for existing file types such as .aspx etc, you will have implement what is already implemented by ASP.NET runtime which is beyond the scope of your requirement.